# Anti-rotation washers (non-turn) washers in non-parallel dropouts?

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, dropouts, alfine

I have a Shimano Alfine 11 Interally-geared hub and am fitting it to an "M5 559 shockproof" recumbent.  The wheel is built and true and runs nicely.

However I have a problem with the anti-rotation washers and my dropouts.  The upper and lower edge are not parallel - they diverge at about 24 degrees.   The dropout is not damaged or bent open.

[image]

Normally this isn't a problem, but an IGH needs an antirotation washer that looks like this.  The "5L" and "5R" version is what I have.

[image: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/images/anti-rotation-washers-labeled800.jpg]

The problem comes in that the tang on the washer is way smaller than the angle of dropout.

[image]

I think the washer's tang should be pressed against the lower part of the dropout, because the hub will want to "roll" forward under tension from the chain.  That is, NOT as pictured.

Your thoughts?   I know I will have to get a set of 7 or 8 to make the cable entry angle work better, but am I risking the health of the frame's dropouts by putting an IGH in at all?

Comment: I know the pictured washer is from the other side - that was a small oversight.  The bowden cable is not yet cut to length either because I don't know what angle the arm will end up on.  Ideally the arm will be above the chain pointing up the rear forkarm (akin to the seatstay, kinda)

Comment: Is the left dropout the same?

Comment: @NathanKnutson yes - the only difference is the integrated hanger on the right hand side, which I'm using for the chain tensioner (required cos bike has small amounts of suspension on rear fork.)

Comment: I can't even name this shape of dropout for a search engine - "non-parallel" returns cold-setting frame links, and "splayed" tends to be dropouts that have been opened up or dug out by electric motors.  What would you call these dropouts ?

Comment: I'd call them tapered, but that doesn't seem to help much either.

Comment: I'm kinda at a loss on this one, I just haven't seen many or any dropouts like this. I intuitively suspect that the rotation washers are only doing their thing in one direction and so it's fine, but then I try and think through whether there's a bearing precession part in there to worry about and I get lost.

Comment: What are the washers made of? If steel, the best solution would be to braze or (spot) weld an extra wedge on there. Not so easy if Al, though a combination of glue and an interlocking shape might get you somewhere - fiddly work with a small file. If Al, perhaps fabricate a whole new one (in Al or brass)

Comment: If it's ok to modify the frame permanently I would cut a wedge from a flat piece of metal and glue it into the dropout to make it parallel.

Comment: @ChrisH the washers are beefy steel, probably cast not stamped.  They're $10NZ each side which is steep too.

Comment: @Nobody that's a good idea - I'll look into pursuing that..  Possibly brazing to a thin washer will be enough to keep it in place on the inside of the dropout.

Comment: Oh and about the health of the dropouts - I don't have time to research the topic, but the Rohloff manual I have here has a table of torques by gear that the dropout needs to take. The highest value is 98% of the pedalling torque. So a lot! There is a reason they offer torque arms for their hub.

Comment: After I ended up doing the calculations for the torque, if you can supply some more information I might as well calculate a ballpark estimate about the strength of the dropout and whether it can take that torque. Information needed: Do you have the CrMo or titanium version (I assume CrMo), is the dropout hollow (I hope not) and some outer measurements: Thickness (I assume is constant), and minimum width along the L formed by the lower part of the dropout.

Comment: Oh and that's not relevant to the question, but which size wheel version do you have and how happy are you with it? :)

Comment: @Nobody getting OT here, ask me in [chat] ?

Comment: Well if you want me to calculate the strength of your dropout then I need that information which is very on topic. :) The rest I can ask in chat.

Answer (score 4):

The torque that the axle sees relative to the frame can happen in both directions as gears change.

For example in the classic Sturmey Archer 3 speed, it's the second gear that is neutral and does not place a torque on the axle.  In third gear the axle will try to twist forwards, and in first gear it will try to twist backwards.

For this reason you really do need an anti-torque washer and you can't leave the gap in the second picture above or below.

I would try to use a normal anti-torque washer against the inside face of the dropout.  This washer will have the square hole to grip the axle.  Then I would try to make a second washer-wedge-combo out of a softer metal (e.g. Al) to go on the outside.  The wedge part of this piece would fill that gap between the red lines in the second picture, but it's strictly functioning as a wedge and can have a round center hole.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to ask your frame manufacturer if the dropout can handle the torque with only anti-rotation washers or if you need a torque arm. Below I derive the formula for the torque (verified, matches the values from Rohloff manual). The values for the Shimano Alfine 11 are (with 42 and 16 teeth sprockets):

1. 0.34191741212614074
2. 0.17844905950632817
3. 0.11379097093382806
4. 0.052934157717756794
5. 0.0019143335726249959
6. -0.04501553707902912
7. -0.08609759693351027
8. -0.12038303693570448
9. -0.15242665752563775
10. -0.17917675544794187
11. -0.2040121204078473

Expressed as a fraction of pedal torque.

To fit an anti-rotation washer you could, as mentioned by others and myself, put a wedge in the open space. Make sure you put the wedge on the side that gets less torque. To fix the wedge it could be glued to the frame or to the dropout or to a separate washer. A good glue connection should be ok because if done right there is little force on the connection and most on the wedge internally.

How to get the amount of torque that is applied to the dropout:

Power is torque times angular velocity. Power at the pedals is thus

P=τ<sub>pedal</sub>ω<sub>pedal</sub>

Power is conserved (minus some drivetrain losses which are ignored).
So

P=τ<sub>pedal</sub>ω<sub>pedal</sub>=τ<sub>hub-in</sub>ω<sub>hub-in</sub>=τ<sub>ground</sub>ω<sub>hub-in</sub>IGHratio(gear)

and thus the input torque to the hub is

τ<sub>hub-in</sub>=τ<sub>pedal</sub>ω<sub>pedal</sub>/ω<sub>hub-in</sub>

and to the ground

τ<sub>ground</sub>=τ<sub>hub-in</sub>·/IGHratio(gear)

The quotient of the angular velocities can be calculated from the
ratio of teeth counts of the sprockets. It's the inverse of the relation of the teeth counts (the more teeth in relation to the other, the slower the sprocket turns in relation to the other). [There](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/alfine-11.html) is a table for IGHratio(gear).

Now we use that

τ<sub>hub-in</sub>-τ<sub>ground</sub>+τ<sub>dropout</sub>=0

by construction and get the result

τ<sub>dropout</sub>

=τ<sub>ground</sub>-τ<sub>hub-in</sub>

=τ<sub>hub-in</sub>(IGHratio(gear)-1)

=τ<sub>pedal</sub>(ω<sub>pedal</sub>/ω<sub>hub-in</sub>)(IGHratio(gear)-1)

=τ<sub>pedal</sub>((#teeth hub)/(#teeth pedal)(1/IGHratio(gear)-1)

Skript:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Rohloff Speedhub
#r = [0, 0.279, 0.316, 0.360, 0.409, 0.464, 0.528, 0.600, 0.682, 0.774, 0.881, 1.000, 1.135, 1.292, 1.467]

# Shimano Alfine 11
r = [0, 0.527, 0.681, 0.770, 0.878, 0.995, 1.134, 1.292, 1.462, 1.667, 1.888, 2.153]

def d(g):
  return((16/42)*(1/r[g]-1))

for i in range(1,len(r)):
  print(str(i) + ".\t" + str(d(i)))
```

And for the curious: The reason the torques are much smaller than with the Rohloff is because the gear ratios are more centered: They are between divided by 2 and multiplied by 2 for the Shimano one and between divided by 4 and times 3/2 for the Rohloff. A smaller part of the reason is that the gear range of the Rohloff one is larger overall.

Comment: Please help with the formatting, I can't get the math (latex) to display.

Comment: I'm not sure tex is enabled on this site. It isn't on every site

Comment: @ChrisH Kind of feels like a deja vu, maybe I was told that before. Anyway, then it stays like that for now.

Comment: I've had a go at it.  Feel free to roll back or edit.  I used a semi-automated approach as all the mappings like `\tau`->`&tau;` could be automated and regexes could handle things like  `_\{([^}]*)\}`->`<sub>$1</sub>`.  You can't get decent fractions in html though; even Wikipedia couldn't last I checked.

Comment: "Below I try to derive the formula for the torque but something went wrong and it doesn't match the values from the Rohloff manual." Is the manual higher? In case you are looking for the peak torque is a power conservation approach correct? If energy is stored, eg through springyness of parts or rotational inertia power conservation of your ansatz might only hold on average while it might be not apply at every moment. This is just meant as a thought. Dealing with such dynamic effects probably cannot be dealt with analytically and in such a brief form.

Comment: @gschenk I think it's more likely there is some "easy" mistake in my attempt which I can't find. My values are much lower but the ratio isn't constant and I think it's too large for such dynamic effects which I think shouldn't be a large part of the total but I might be wrong again.

Comment: @gschenk Just found the mistake, now the values match. It was the simple stupid mistake I expected.

Comment: brilliant Nobody!