# Need anti-rotational washer for Pedalease ebike

Tags: repair

[image]

My Pedalease e-bike is missing one of the rotational washer and I have attached a photo of the the original ones it came with and I hope you could help me.

---

[image: From PDF linked already]
[image: Also from PDF]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that's not a very good photo.  You need to tell us more about the bike, especially the pedals and the crank arms.  Photos of the bike, pedals, and crankarms and a clear photo of the one washer that you do have would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, you need a clearer photograph. I can't tell what it is you're looking for, except that it's some small-ish black thing. Try taking it on the windowsill so there's more light -- your camera will focus better and you won't need to hold it as till to get a clear shot. Also, we're not a shop, so we don't have things in stock. We're just a bunch of people on the internet who try to answer people's questions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's a photo of the assembly manual that has a picture of the part

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com is not a shop.  We don't sell stuff here, we give assistance and advice and suggestions based on the depth and variety of all our cycling experiences.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's worthy of being an answer.   My LBS stocks shimano antirotation washers, but they are $10 each.  OP should check all the packaging closely for missed parts (there may be more than just these two)  and then absolutely go back to the seller/shop/provider.

Comment: I would suggest that you take the picture and/bike to your local bike shop.

Comment: Here's a better picture: https://download.elecycles.com/manual/Ebike-Conversion-Kit-Manual/iMortor1.0-user-manual.pdf

Comment: The washer is shown being used on page 30 of the PDF.

Comment: page 29 is quite terrifying, telling user to grind and file their fork to give it dropouts.  Also phrasing like "In case handlebar size of your love car is slightly
small"

Comment: Possibly related questions at 
 https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/what-is-the-technical-name-for-this-nut-bolt-thing-with-inner-hubs  and  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/anti-rotation-washers-non-turn-washers-in-non-parallel-dropouts

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've bought a bike and are trying to build it yourself. If parts were missing, you should ask the seller (first choice) or the manufacturer to supply all the missing parts. If the bike isn't new, the seller should still know where to get parts.

Answer (score 1):

If your supplier has gone under or no longer deals with these bikes then you may have to buy something.

[image]

Shimano have a range of antirotation washers for internally-geared hubs and their drum brakes. Notice here how they have matched and mirror pairs, and the angle between the flats of the hole and the tang vary between each set ?

You will need to figure out what the angle is between the flats on your axle, and the dropout.  Using paper as a template, and a protractor and a level is much more reliable than eyeballing it.

That PDF implies the blue battery has to sit level or very near to level.

Comment: They're not cheap either.