# What kind of nut is used on Shimano hub dynamo with rollerbrake?

Tags: shimano, dynamo, roller-brake

I tried using the normal cap nut that is also used for my Shimano internal gear hub on my back wheel. The issue I have is that the axle on power side is quite short and the nut does not get enough "grip". When tightened, it jumps back. The axle on the brake side is much longer and the nut sits tight.

Another thing that bothers me, is that the axle has a groove that looks like an anti rotation washer similar to the ones that come with the Nexus internal gear hubs belong there. I have spend a few hours looking on the Internet, but I cannot find any information on what kind of nut should go there.

The dynamo hubs model number is DH-C6000-3R.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you just need the right size nut.

Comment: With your part number you can search Shimano's handbook database. They have highly detailed exploded views of all their components with installation guides.

Comment: @DanielRHicks thanks for pointing me in the right right direction. I did look at the exploded views before, but they don't show the nuts. However, I found the nut in the manual for the [front rollerbrake](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-HB-IM40-1562F.pdf). The axle requires a M9 cap nut, my rear hub uses a 3/8" cap nut. Thanks Shimano! I ordered the cap nut and will update my answer after checking out if that really works.

Comment: You should note that you can buy either size nut at just about any hardware store (if you don't have one in your junk drawer already).

Comment: @Swifty, I wanted to mention both, but only one mention is possible per comment.

Comment: That groove is not for a shimano antirotation washer - they're pictured in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/  and those axles have two flats, and a tang that sits in the dropout on the frame.    Its probably for either a boring conventional tab washer (way cheaper than the $himano ones) or remote chance its a valley for an electric wire for a hub dynamo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ordered a M9 cap nut and its fits.

Comment: Did you make sure to get a high tensile nut?  Not a cheap hardware store one made of cheese-grade mild steel?

Comment: @Criggie I just saw your comment. I actually tried to find one at a hardware store, but as far as I remember the thread count was too low. I then ordered a Shimano one from a bicycle store. Good to know that there is also a quality difference